# How to update redshift column: simple text replacement

Tags: sql-update, amazon-redshift, insert-update

I have a large `target` table with columns (`id`, `value`). I want to update `value='old'` to `value='new'`.

The simplest way would be to `UPDATE target SET value='new' WHERE value='old';`

However, this deletes and creates new rows and is not recommended, possibly. So I tried to do a merge column update:

```
# staging
CREATE TABLE stage (LIKE target INCLUDING DEFAULTS);
INSERT INTO stage (SELECT id, value FROM target WHERE value=`old`);
UPDATE stage SET value='new' WHERE value='old'; # ??? how do you update value?

# merge
begin transaction;
UPDATE target 
SET value = stage.value FROM stage
WHERE target.id = stage.id and target.distkey = stage.distkey; # collocated join?
end transaction;

DROP TABLE stage;
```

1. This can't be the best way of creating the table stage: I have to do all these `UPDATE` delete/writes when I update this way. Is there a way to do it in the `INSERT`?
2. Is it necessary to force the collocated join when I use `CREATE TABLE LIKE`?

Answer (score 2):

Are you updating all the rows in the table?

If yes you can use CTAS (create table as) which is recommended method

Assuming you table looks like this

```
table1
id, col1,col2, value
```

You can use the following SQL to create a new table

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_table AS 
  SELECT id, col1,col2, 'new_value' 
  FROM table1;
```

After you verify data in tmp_table

```
DROP TABLE table1;
ALTER TABLE tmp_table RENAME TO table1;
```

If you are not updating all the rows you can use a filter to do a CTAS and insert the rest of the rows to the new table, let me know if you need more info if this is the case

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_table AS 
  SELECT id, col1,col2, 'new_value' 
  FROM table1
  WHERE value = 'old'

INSERT INTO tmp_table SELECT * from table1;
```

Next step would be DROP the tmp table and rename table1

Update: Based on your comment you can do the following, let me know if this solves your case.

This method basically creates a new table to replace your existing table.
I have used some of your code

```
CREATE TABLE stage (LIKE target INCLUDING DEFAULTS);
INSERT INTO stage SELECT id, 'new' FROM target WHERE value=`old`;
```

Above INSERT inserts rows to be updated with 'new', no need to run an UPDATE after this.

Bring unchanged rows

```
INSERT INTO stage SELECT id, value FROM target WHERE value!=`old`;
```

After this point you have `target` table which is your original table intact

`stage` table will have both sets of rows, updated rows with 'new' value and rows you did not want to change

To replace your `target` with `stage`

```
DROP TABLE target;
```

or to keep it further verification

```
ALTER TABLE target RENAME TO target_old; 

ALTER TABLE stage RENAME TO target;
```

Comment: I'm not updating all rows, only rows where the column `value` has a value of `'old'`, and I want to update those rows to `'new'`. That's the second case. I don't want to insert the rest of the rows to a new table either, I just want to do a text replacement of some rows where their column value is an old one

Comment: Updated the answer based on your comment, please let me know if this works for you

Comment: A few questions!
1. Is this how you'd do a simple text replacement? By rewriting the _entire_ table? My `target` table is many columns, of which I only care about `id` and `value`. Can you explain why that'd be better than a simple update? That seems like more writes.

Comment: 2. If I was doing this with more columns than just the two above, would the initial insert into staging look like `INSERT INTO stage SELECT id, 'new' as value FROM target WHERE value='old';`?

Comment: I do not know all the details about your use case. You have presented a case using AWS documentation samples, without knowing all the details I have proposed "a" solution, unarguably there are more ways to solve this including a simple UPDATE statement. Also to answer your questions, 1 Yes I would do it this way. 2 Yes.

Comment: Okay, I just think it's not really reasonable for a large table just to replace a few text strings. Information that it was a large table has been in the question from the start, as with info that I only wanted to update some rows in the column.

Answer (score 2):

From a redshift developer:

This case doesn't require an upsert, or update+insert, and it is fine to just run the update:

```
UPDATE target SET value='new' WHERE value='old';
```

Another way would be to `INSERT` the rows you need and `DELETE` the other rows, but that's unnecessarily complicated.